# How Audio steganography is called secure?

Tags: internet, steganography

Everyone can extract the information from audio file then how its called secure. Means if we hide the text message into an audio file its the possibility that the third person can extract then how its secure? 
What is the security over sharing internet using this technique? Anyone can explain?

Comment: Please add sources who claims that this is secure and under what conditions. I could imagine that it is only claimed to be secure if the message is not just hidden but additionally encrypted which is the case with many steganography tools.

Comment: First question question you need to ask is if steganography considered secure at all? Hiding a message is not securing it.

Answer (score 3):

Steganography is an Obfuscation technique. It doesn't offer any sort of confidentiality to the data unless an additional encryption is used. The above said is true irrespective of what kind of file you try to embed your data.

Secure usage of steganography is when you use encryption along with it.  Suppose you are trying to hide message M in file F.

Step 1: Encrypt message M. C = E(M)

Step 2: Use the Least significant bit of each byte of the file F to store the following - C and Details of Encryption Algorithm

Comment: Why should i add details of encryption algorithm ? If i want something to be secure i shouldn't give you those informations. The party i want to send it to will know the algorithm but noone else should. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: @ShinobiUltra I'd suggest you read this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle